# Why is $f(x,y)$ said to be discontinuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Why is 
$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$}\\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}$ said to be discontinuous at $(0,0)$?

I am supposed to show that this function is not continuous at (0,0), but as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$, $f(x,y)$ approaches $0=f(0,0)$. So what did I miss here?

Comment: You missed the curve $\: y = x^2 \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Try approaching $(0, 0)$ along the curve $y = x^2$.

Comment: Here it is! Thank you...

Comment: or the curve  $y=-{ x }^{ 2 }$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=x^{2}$. Consider $f(x,x^{2})=\frac{x^{4}}{2x^{4}}=\frac{1}{2}$.So it's not continuous at $(0,0)$. (Even it does not have a limit, you can plug $y=0$)

Comment: OK, but two comments beat you to the same argument.